# Problem with deepcopy?

Tags: python, deep-copy

### Source

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Field(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = []

class BaseForm(object):
    pass

class MetaForm(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['fields'] = dict([(name, deepcopy(attrs.pop(name))) for name, obj in attrs.items() if isinstance(obj, Field)])
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Form(BaseForm):
    __metaclass__ = MetaForm

class MyForm(Form):
    field1 = Field()

f1 = MyForm()
f1.fields['field1'].errors += ['error msg']

f2 = MyForm()
print f2.fields['field1'].errors
```

### Output

```
['error msg']
```

### Question

Why does it output that? I thought I cloned the errors list before modifying it, and that they shouldn't both refer to the same list?

Comment: It looks like `MetaForm.__new__` is only called *once* for `MyForm` (and once for `Form`) even though I've constructed *two* `MyForms`. How does that work? My understanding was that it needed to called each time it was constructed. I guess it operates on a class level? Where's the best place to move the `deepcopy` statement then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting the `dict` `fields` in the `metaclass`, you are creating a class attribute.

The `__new__` method you defined is only run once -- on class creation.

**Update**

You should manipulate `attrs` in `__new__` like you are, but name it something like `_fields`. Then create an `__init__` method that performs a `deepcopy` into an `attribute` called `fields`.

Comment: Ah.. guess I had a fundamental misunderstanding of how `__new__` worked.

Comment: An `__init__` on which class? The `BaseForm`? Because `MetaForm.__init__` is only called once as well, isn't it?

Comment: `__init__` for the `Form` class

Comment: Well... the `Form` class is deliberately left blank, so I'll stuff it in the base. Same diff. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A more explicit solution:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class Field(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.errors = []

class BaseForm(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fields = deepcopy(self.fields)

class MetaForm(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs['fields'] = dict([(name, attrs.pop(name)) for name, obj in attrs.items() if isinstance(obj, Field)])
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

class Form(BaseForm):
    __metaclass__ = MetaForm

class MyForm(Form):
    field1 = Field()

f1 = MyForm()
f1.fields['field1'].errors += ['error msg']

f2 = MyForm()
print f2.fields['field1'].errors
```

Just moved the `deepcopy` into `BaseForm.__init__` instead, which actually *is* called each time a `MyForm` is instantiated.